# OpenSessionInViewInterceptor not working with Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-criteria

I am using the OpenSessionInViewInterceptor in my code
Code snippet:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.service" />

<bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="openSessionInViewInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abcTest" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>


<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.abc.entity" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="applicationUtil" class="com.abc.util.ApplicationUtil" />

<bean id="auctionDao" class="com.abc.dao.AuctionDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />

</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean name="openSessionInViewInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Other details I am not mentioning here.
In my DAO I have a method

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public List<Item> fetchCurrentlyActiveBids() throws RuntimeException {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Item.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("isActive", true));
    List<Item> itemList = criteria.list();
    //session.close();
    return itemList;
}
```

I am able to hit my dao and get data for few times. Then again when I am repeatedly calling this method using rest client (thorugh rest end point) I get the following error:

{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "statusDescription": "Internal Server Error",
  "errorMessage": "nested transactions not supported"
}`

Not able to understand why nested transaction not supported is showing? If I use OpenSessionInViewInterceptor it should automatically close the session after use. Kindly suggest a solution

**Edited Configuration Section**

Comment: Your `hibernate.current_session_context_class` breaks proper integration. Remove it. Also you shouldn't start transactions yourself so remove the calls to begin transaction. Finally if you also have `mvc:annotation-driven` you are registering the interceptor in a wrong way.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum I am using <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> Will it be a problem?

Comment: Have you read my comment? Yes that is a problem that is what I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @M.Deinum It worked like a charm. Thanks. I just removed the stated two lines and that's it :)

Comment: Also you shouldn't be using `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` as it is deprecated. Use `<mvc:annotation-driven />` instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have updated the configuration section. Could you please have a look and suggest me suitable changes